# How can I extract selective keys through JSONata?

Tags: json, jsonata

I just want to extract Product Name, ProductID, SKU from the below object

```
 {
        "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
        "ProductID": 858383,
        "SKU": "0406654608",
        "Description": {
          "Colour": "Purple",
          "Width": 300,
          "Height": 200,
          "Depth": 210,
          "Weight": 0.75
        },
        "Price": 34.45,
        "Quantity": 2
}
```

Expected Result:

```
{
   "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
   "ProductID": 858383,
   "SKU": "0406654608"
}
```

Tried Solutions:

1. Direct Object Mapping:

   ```
   { "Product Name": `Product Name`, "ProductID": ProductID, "SKU": SKU }
   ```
2. Sift:

   ```
   $sift(function($v, $k) {$k ~> /^Product Name|ProductID|SKU/})
   ```

---

Need a simpler way to do it. Something like:

```
{ `Product Name`, ProductID, SKU}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched?

Comment: I've been trying for some time now with no success. Just know, Im close. I can easily create an object and map the relevant nodes. Or I can use sift. But Im trying to find out whether there's an easier way to solve it.

Comment: Can you include your attempts?

Comment: $sift(function($v, $k) {$k ~> /^Product Name|ProductID|SKU/})

Comment: Do you understand how objects work in JavaScript? That's a good starting point.

Comment: Not sure whether it'll work the same in JSONata. Anyways I'll try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172798/discussion-between-bin-and-jhpratt).

Comment: maybe something like `[**.'Product Name', ProductID, SKU]`

Comment: It will result in an array. Check http://try.jsonata.org/r1lgSnOlX

Comment: obviously .. because you didn't specify what is the expected result, "extract Product Name, ProductID, SKU" can be interpreted in many ways ..

Comment: as a side note, if you are not limited to JSONata, there are "easier" alternatives like jq https://jqplay.org/s/F6JiRBGyDj

Answer (score 0):

The obvious alternative is:

```
{ "Product Name": `Product Name`, "ProductID": ProductID, "SKU": SKU }
```

or a bit shorter if the positions are always the same:

```
{ "Product Name": *[0], "ProductID": *[1], "SKU": SKU }
```

Comment: For properties with spaces in them (e.g. Product Name), you can also use backtics to avoid the **. stuff --
    {
      "Product Name": \`Product Name\`,
      "ProductID": ProductID,
      "SKU": SKU
    }

Comment: Thanks @Slai . However, I'm already aware of this method. I'll update the question description with these details.